# VB.net 2 table into 1 table without key ID

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

all. Currently I am using VB.net 2008 with mdb database.I have 2 table in mdb with 3 column each without any primary key.I wish to query it into single table to load into my form.How should I do it?

My Table 1 =
Date & Time,
Name,
Total,

My Table 2 =
Date & Time,
Name,
Total,

Output Table =
Date & Time,
Name,
Total,

** There are no any same data within the table and no primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query:

```
SELECT [Date & Time], [Name], [Total]
FROM [My Table 1]
UNION SELECT [Date & Time], [Name], [Total]
FROM [My Table 2];
```

with filter [Total]>0 and order by [Date & Time] try it:

```
SELECT [Date & Time], [Name], [Total]
FROM [My Table 1] WHERE [Total]>0
UNION SELECT [Date & Time], [Name], [Total]
FROM [My Table 2] WHERE [Total]>0
ORDER BY [Date & Time];
```

Comment: Thanks, this method will do.But just found it can only do sorting on Table 1, can we do sorting on Table 2 also? Also it seems can not do filter on it eg.  ( Total > 0 )

Comment: You can write your query?

Comment: Thanks all solved, I just use method select with select